# ./setup.py nosetests error: <some_package>: Not a directory

Tags: python-2.7, setuptools, nosetests

I have a package with the following `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

# Some dependency_links magic

setup(
    name='dc-gce',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests', 'tests.*']),
    dependency_links=dependency_links,
    install_requires=[
        'google-api-python-client',
        'dc-tools>=0.0.1,<0.1.0'
    ],
    tests_require=[
        'dc-gae>=0.0.1,<0.1.0',
        'httplib2',
        'webob'
    ],
    test_suite='tests')
```

It depends on a package with this `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='dc-tools',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests', 'tests.*']),
    zip_safe=True,
    test_suite='tests')
```

When I run `python setup.py test` in the first package, all dependencies are downloaded and all the tests work fine.

However, when I run `python setup.py nosetests` instead, I get this error:

```
error: <pwd>/dc_tools-0.0.1-py2.7.egg/dc: Not a directory
```

The `dc` directory mentioned is a properly setup namespace in all packages and it does exist in the egg. The egg is zipped though.

I fixed the same issue for the `dc-gae` dependency by adding `zip_safe=False` to its `setup.py`. I don't feel this is a proper fix though.

**Edit**: I tried `python setup.py test`. that worked. I think it's a bug in nose.

Comment: Are you using any version control like svn?

Comment: I am using git and I use `git clean -xdf` to clean any files between tests. I am also using virtualenv.

Comment: Try adding `include_package_data=True`.

Comment: Didn't help. It does work when I run `pip install .` first. However I feel this should not be necessary.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of setuptools?  I've had strange problems that were resolved by updating from an older version.

Comment: Upgrading setuptools doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [bug in nose 1.3.1](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/issues/792#issuecomment-40894019) and has been fixed for the upcoming release.